# How should this PUT curl be converted to python requests?

Tags: python, curl

How can I convert this CURL PUT request to python requests:

The `curl` is

```
curl -X PUT "https://example.com" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -d "{  \"userName\": \"exampleuser\",  \"password\": \"examplepass\"}"
```

Currently got

```
headers = {"accept": "application/json",
           "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json"}
data = {'\"userName\"': '\"exampleuser\"',
        '\"password\"': '\"examplepass\"'}

response = requests.put(url=url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Currently getting a 401 response. Unfortunately, the [curl converter](https://curl.trillworks.com/#python) does not recognise it.

Comment: 401 mean you were not authorized, are you sure your password is not just wrong?

Comment: My password is correct

Comment: ok, just to debug could you try to make the request with json like this `dumps:data = {'sender':   'Alice',
    'receiver': 'Bob',
    'message':  'We did it!'}
data_json = simplejson.dumps(data)` Of course replace it with your values :-)

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you escaped the quotes of the json

In Python, you shouldn't need to

```
data = {'userName' : 'exampleuser',
    'password': 'examplepass'}
```

Then, you're sending json, so do `json=data` instead of `data=data`

Comment: Tried that, makes no difference

Comment: How about `json=data` instead of `data=data`?

Comment: BOOM! That's the ticket! Thanks! It's always the most tiny thing...